# Unhandled Exception: Connection closed before full header was received unable to solve this

Tags: http, flutter

I am using following package for API request

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
Future<List<HomeModel>> GetDataHome() {
    return http.post("http://dummy.com/api/home_api.php",
        body: {'user_id': user_id}).then((dynamic res) {
      print(res.toString());
      var dat = json.decode(res.body);
      print(dat);
      obj = dat;
      setState(() {
        account_status = dat['account_status'];
   });
      return (dat["data"] as List).map((p) => HomeModel.fromJson(p)).toList();
    });
  }
```

and i got this error :

```
E/flutter (11109): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: Connection closed before full header was received
```

i can't get it where it comes from , i have checked API in postman its working fine
In app sometimes it's successfully send my request and almost all time it throws this Exception.
I have tried using solution that it is for android version pie and Q but had get the issue with oreo too. 
Help wanted!!!

Comment: Try adding `await` before you return `await return http.post(...) ` and add `async` to the `getDataHome`

Comment: not working @dev-aentgs

Comment: It is an open issue on [github 41573](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/41573).
 
Not sure if this will work but [try](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/41573#issuecomment-582244735)